# How to set a digital out to 24V Vcc

Tags: switches, digital-logic, 24v

I want a curcuit with 3.3V and 24V supply. The micro will use the 3.3V supply, which needs to be able to set multiple industrial 24V digital outputs.

My plan was a simple op amp, but as far as I know no op amp will actually achieve an output of 100% of Vcc, no matter the gain. Is there a cheap and simple way to do this? Relays seems expensive and big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a NPN/NFET transistor as an open collector/open drain output. Use a resistor pull-up if your load doesn't have one. Alternatively, opto-isolators will give you the same functionality with the freedom to separate your power and ground domains. I would not recommend using an op-amp.

Now, to clear up some misconceptions:

1. CMOS op-amps will get you pretty close to the power supply rails. For example, the OPA211 from TI will get you within 0.2V of your power supply rails when sinking or sourcing load of 1-3mA, which isn't too bad.
2. Unless your  load is insanely picky about logic levels, (which makes no sense at all on industrial equipment), you don't actually need exactly 24V and 0V. Most equipment I've seen can tolerate +/- 10%, and logic levels are fairly forgiving. Check your load's datasheet, and you will find input logic high and logic low thresholds. Sparkfun has an excellent writeup on [logic levels](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/225).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd need 100% of Vcc due to a signaling problem in the past. After mysteriously fixing it with a a relay in between, I assumed the small differences in Vcc gave the problem. But you're right, I doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just to piggy-back on Leon's answer...

Use the 3.3V signal to turn on and off a transistor.  The bottom of the transistor is tied to GND.  The top has a pull-up resistor to +24V and a tap go to the output.

When the signal is off, the transistor is off, and the output is pull-up to +24V.

When the signal is on, the transistor turns on, and the output is shorted to GND.

Answer (score 2):

In environments like this you usually want to make sure you have some protection against back flow. One of the easiest ways to deal with this is with an opto-coupler or Opto-isolator.

You can buy ICs that are an all in 1 package, but from a functional level it is an LED (something like IR LED) that is turned on by your microcontroller, it then shines on a receiver that acts like a switch based off of the LED shining on it or not. You can then use this in your circuit to turn on or off your 24V output.

The big advantage here is that if you have a back flow of current on the 24V side, there is no way for the lower voltage LED side to be affected.

Comment: What if the uC voltage on the 3.3V is derived from the 24V supply? You still get any protection out of a opto coupler?

Answer (score 0):

Use suitable BJTs or MOSFETs. Types will depend on the current to be controlled.

Comment: Not much detail, is there?